# "afraid to speak up"

Tags: word-choice

What is a the adjective that describes someone who is afraid to speak up?

For example: As a young child, I was ***_*_**, but as I grew up, I transformed into a courageous and determined woman.

Answer (score 6):

I think **timid** could be a good option.

Comment: Also _shy, reticent, silent, quiet, pensive_. Among others.

Answer (score 2):

**Options** (about and from are followed by "*speaking* up")

shy from

reticent to

shrinking from

fearful of

nervous about

wary of

embarrassed about

abashed from

suspicious to

shrinking from

timorous to

retiring from

hesitant to

timorous from

Answer (score 0):

Consider ***diffident.***

> lacking confidence in one's own ability, worth, or fitness; timid; shy.
>
> restrained or reserved in manner, conduct, etc.

Answer (score 0):

To describe being afraid or unwilling to speak up, I think ***reticent*** is probably the best choice, but in your sentence I think ***timid*** better contrasts *courageous and determined*.

Answer (score -2):

*Hotdog* is a good one because it symbolizes the innocence of childhood as well as the taste of youth and freedom.

How to use it in a sentence:

> The hotdog in my mouth felt wet.
>   I used to speak up but I have become a hotdog.

Literally, my job is a hotdog mascot for Oscar Meyer.

Comment: This is completely opposite the common definition of "one who performs in a showy, conspicuous, or ostentatious manner so as to attract attention", with synonyms such as "show-off" and "showboat".  Do you have any citations supporting this suggested usage?